# The retention period of the window store KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001 must be no smaller than its window size plus the grace period

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I had a day window with initially grace period set as O. Got a new requirement to add grace period of 15 mins.

Kafka streaming version: 2.1

Code Snippet-

KTable, JsonNode> profileAgg =
                transactions
                        .groupByKey()
                        .windowedBy(                            TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(86400)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(900)))

But somehow I am getting exception on process startup. How do I increase retention period?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The retention period of the window store KSTREAM-FILTER-0000000001 
must be no smaller than its window size plus the grace period. Got size=[86400000], grace=[900000], retention=[86400000]

Comment: Please mark this issue resolved, This is resolved after adding Materialized.retention

Comment: If you find solution, you should add it answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved after adding retention with option Materialized.retention